# Spyder cannot launch: spyder: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, pip, spyder

I have installed spyder by `pip3 install spyder` on mac. However, when I cannot launch it from bash and it would show `spyder: command not found`.

I have follow the instructions on its [Github page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), and I have also have its dependencies like PyQt5 installed.

Is there a way to install spyder without installing the Anaconda distribution? 
Thank you.

Comment: Try the `spyder3` command, not just `spyder`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*)

The command to run Spyder when it's installed in Python 3 is `spyder3`, not `spyder`, but only when Spyder is installed with `pip`.

---

Now, about this:

> Is there a way to install spyder without installing the Anaconda distribution?

Our official answer is:

1. If you are new to Python or the Scientific Python ecosystem, we *strongly* recommend you to install and use Anaconda. It comes with Spyder and all its dependencies, along with the most important Python scientific libraries (i.e. Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib, IPython, etc) in a single, easy to use environment.
2. We also support `pip`, but please be aware that `pip` installations are for advanced users with good knowledge of *all* Spyder dependencies.

Given that a simple `Tab` in a terminal after `spyder` would have given you `spyder3`, I'd say you're not very experienced. So my suggestion is: please consider using Anaconda.

Comment: How do you install `spyder3`? I [see in the setup.py](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/setup.py#L210) that `spyder3` is only for Linux. The OP asked about mac. Did I miss something?

Comment: When you install Spyder with `pip`, we use `setuptools` to automatically create the Spyder launching script for *all* OSes. This is done in [this part](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/setup.py#L320-L325) of our `setup.py`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Mac application installed in /Applications, you may want to try the `open` command:

`open -a Spyder`