# How to resolve "command not found error". when spyder3 command is given in cmd prompt

Tags: python, spyder

I installed spyder separately using pip. I installed required packages along with spyder. When spyder3 command is given, Command not found error is shown

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python3`, then it is `spyder3`. Else, if it python 2, you are going to have to use `spyder`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878909/11059315) for more details.

Comment: Look at the link; Why don't you try installing Anaconda?

Comment: Sir, I initially installed anaconda but then it didn't work. I couldn't open anaconda-navigator. I tried to open spyder but couldn't either. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it didn't help

Comment: @SreeKeerthiReddy -- Could you should the output of `pip -V` and `python -V`?